# Can't display any graph with Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, graph, sigma.js

I want to visualize a large network graph on a web interface. After a few days of search, I decided to use Sigma.js because it looks simple and it's HTML5 compatible.

The problem is that I can't display any graph example from Sigma.js web page, even when I use the minimal code that the author has on Sigma.js's homepage. I even copy-pasted entire web pages, with right click-view code, but in vain ([like this](http://sigmajs.org/examples/gexf_example.html)). I have pasted all the necessary files in the same folder that the simple .html file is located (css files, js files and even the .gexf file that the example needs) but I only get a page with a black rectangle and nothing more. The graph isn't displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to first build the sigma.js file, as the author mentions in the code repository of the library in GitHub? I need this tool to visualize the graph (I'm going to feed the graph with data on the fly) but I can't even experiment with some simple code! I even followed [that "guide"](http://noduslabs.com/radar/sigma-js-online-graph-visualization-tool/) and did every step but I can't anything working.

Webstudio: Microsoft Expression Web 4 and OS: Windows 8 Pro (I tried opening the web pages in IE10, FF17 and Chrome 23).

Comment: This is a question that would be much more appropriate for the Sigma.js forum.

Comment: @PiXel1225: Can you maybe accept an answer if it worked out for you?

Comment: @MERose: All answers were published 6 months to a year *after* my original question. After all that time I have obviously found my answer and now I couldn't remember what went wrong to mark something as possible answer or not.

Answer (score 8):

The div you want to have your graph has to be `absolute` positioned. I think it's a canvas issue.

so the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://sigmajs.org/js/sigma.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sigmatest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sigma.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sigma-parent">
      <div id="sigma-example">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the css

```
#sigma-parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}    

#sigma-example {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

the js in `sigmatest.js`

```
function init() {
  var sigRoot = document.getElementById('sigma-example');
  var sigInst = sigma.init(sigRoot);
  sigInst.addNode('hello',{
    label: 'Hello',
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    size: 5,
    color: '#ff0000'
  }).addNode('world',{
    label: 'World !',
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    size: 3,
    color: '#00ff00'
  }).addEdge('hello_world','hello','world').draw();
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
} else {
  window.onload = init;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't help as many people, but in my case it was simply that I didn't specify `x` or `y` properties for each node. I was trying to use the `forceAtlas2` algorithm to automatically "place" my nodes, not realizing they had to be drawn in some position first in order for the layout to then apply.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded this file http://sigmajs.org/data/arctic.gexf 
and refered the path properly in the code

Comment: Try this   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/master/examples/data/arctic.gexf

Answer (score 0):

Sigma js has browser compatibilty issue. Try updating the bowser or use some other browser.

I work with firefox and it works fine.