# Blank canvas with sigma.js via htmlwidgets in R

Tags: r, sigma.js

I can run the sample example ediaspora.gexf.xml provided by [htmlwidgets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/vignettes/develop_intro.html) to get sigma.js in R, and I get a graph that I can play a little bit with. However, if I try different files, say another [example](https://gephi.org/gexf/format/basic.html), I get a blank canvas where I would expect to get a simple graph. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: I tried the JSON given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795125/json-is-not-read-by-sigma-js) which was missing positions (x,y) without more success. I also tried adding positions in the other [example](https://gephi.org/gexf/format/basic.html) I gave, but my attempt did not work.

Comment: The problem might not be with R. I tried running examples like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611443/cant-display-any-graph-with-sigma-js) and [this](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/61), and I either get a blank canvas or a gray box. I tried Chromium and Firefox in Ubuntu.